# StringRedisSerializer converts String to byte[]，But why am I seeing strings not byte[] in the redis client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih2f3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCruM.png)
why am I seeing strings not byte[] in the redis client?
Isn't it the role of StringRedisSerializer to convert strings to byte[]?

What is the role of JdkSerializationRedisSerializer, GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer?

stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set("hello","world");
stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set("hello","world");

Comment: Don’t post code as image, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Redis stores everything as bytes. It doesn't know what string encoding is. The client you are using knows this and just spits out the data. So, if your string happens to contains nice, neat, ASCII data—which the world `world` certainly is—it'll happily print that.